# access denied on localhost .htacces

Tags: .htaccess

i have a private section where specific users can login on my system (restricted to 4 users)

i want to add IP restriction in the .htaccess using:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
order allow,deny
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from 192.168
allow from 67.xx.xx
# etc..
deny from all
</Limit>
```

but i get this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

when i try to access this site locally (i have lamp on my desktop installed, my host file is setup correctly and my apache config is good too)

if I go to my site locally i can see my site with mod-rewrite and errordocument. everything is working fine

why do i get an access denied when i put the restrictin?

Comment: Are you accessing it via localhost or via a domain name?  Also, what do you see in the apache error logs - you might have a permissions problem on the .htaccess file for instance.

Comment: Paul i have my .htaccess setup with rules (mod-rewrite) and its working, also I have ErrorDocument setup and its working fine.

Comment: Trent, I can see the point of localhost and your private address-space, since these are trusted.  Is the 67... IP fixed or this just going to create a maintenance hassle.  Have you thought of configuring Apache authentication or even just using some private cookie with a RewriteRule to reject all requests which fails on `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !\bkey=someprivatekey\b`.  Just another option

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can first deny and then allow:

```
order deny,allow

deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
allow from 192.168
allow from 67.xx.xx
# etc..
```

obviously I can not test with your setup, but that's what I do.

Comment: oh thank you very much, i had to remove the space after the comma, it gave me an internal server error but it works now thanks